# Need help removing a contour from image using Open CV python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mask, contour

I am trying to remove this rectangular [contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd19V.jpg) from the binary image of this [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd19V.jpg).

I have tried to use this tutorial https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/09/removing-contours-image-using-python-opencv/ but it is not yielding the desired results and I am not very clear of what the syntax does.

```
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 61, 10)
cntrs, hiearchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
largest_areas = sorted(cntrs, key=cv2.contourArea)
largest_cntr = [largest_areas[-1]] #rectangular contour or largest contour
    
mask = np.ones(thresh.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255    
cv2.drawContours(mask, largest_cntr, -1, 0, -1)
thresh = cv2.bitwise_and(thresh, thresh, mask=mask)
cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("After", thresh)
```

In the end I get a black-filled image. How can I remove the contour from the image properly?
[image]
[image]

Full code:

```
import cv2,os, glob
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np


folder_dir = os.getcwd()
print(folder_dir)
img = cv2.imread(folder_dir + "/imgur.jpg")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 31, 10)
cntrs, hiearchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
largest_areas = sorted(cntrs, key=cv2.contourArea)
largest_cntr = [largest_areas[-1]] #rectangular contour or largest contour
    
mask = np.ones(thresh.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255    
cv2.drawContours(mask, largest_cntr, -1, 0, -1)
thresh = cv2.bitwise_and(thresh, thresh, mask=mask)
cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("After", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The code works as expected. The final result does not contain the outer rectangle. There is something wrong at your end. Can you share the complete code?

Comment: @JeruLuke I have now edited the post to include the full code, which returns the same result as my post details. By the way, imgur.jpg in my code refers to the photo dubbed "original image" in the description that is linked in the imgur link.

Comment: Again I executed your code with the given image and the outer rectangle was removed. Use a different variable for `cv2.bitwise_and` function.

Comment: Here is the [result I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb6cy.jpg) for the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nO2P.jpg)

Comment: @JeruLuke I downloaded the [image you use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nO2P.jpg) and it works perfectly with the results being as you said, but when I use the image I download from the [imgur link I posted](https://imgur.com/mydZVKt) it fails. There must be some difference between our two images, but I am not sure what it is that is causing this change. Did you download from the link using the imgur downloading button with the three dots?

Comment: I just right clicked the image and downloaded it

Comment: @JeruLuke I further detail the difference here:  One works and one doesn't for some reason: https://imgur.com/a/VVCXJCz You can try downloading again and see if there is a change

Comment: I will try and update